# Implementing Sobel Gradient in Octave

Tags: matlab, image-processing, octave, sobel

So I am supposed to apply a Sobel filter on an image in Octave, but I am not allowed to use any functions from the image package. I wrote the code but my output is just a black image. Here is what I have so far:

```
%Sobel Gradient

kx= [1 ,0 ,-1; 2,0,-2; 1, 0 ,-1];
ky= [1,2,1; 0,0, 0; -1, -2 ,-1];

H = conv2(kx,im2double(my_img),'same');
V = conv2(ky,im2double(my_img),'same');
E = sqrtm(H.*H + V.*V);
figure 4
imshow(E, [])
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Try normalising the image prior to display - I am no good on `Octave` but something like `E = max(0, E ./ (max(max(E)) / 255));`

Comment: @MarkSetchell the square brakets on `imshow` shoudl be doing that job

Comment: @AnderBiguri Ok, thank you! My assertion that I am no good on Octave was correct :-)

Comment: @ray this is not a duplicate, the reason it does not work is very different!

Comment: @AnderBiguri I flagged it as a duplicate because it contains the correct implementation of the Sobel filter.

Comment: @rayryeng I see! I still think its not a duplicate, but if you think so feel free to dupe it again ;)

Comment: @AnderBiguri I can't lol. You've already reopened it.  It's OK. Have a vote from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few minor mistakes, and your problem is fixed:

1) you convolve your image by the kernel, not the opposite. Mainly because you are using `'same'` and that will output the size of the first input, 3x3.

2) you dont want a [matrix square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix), just the normal elementwise square root.

```
my_img=imread('cameraman.tif') % available in MATLAB, not sure octave
kx= [1 ,0 ,-1; 2,0,-2; 1, 0 ,-1];
ky= [1,2,1; 0,0, 0; -1, -2 ,-1];

H = conv2(im2double(my_img),kx,'same');
V = conv2(im2double(my_img),ky,'same');
E = sqrt(H.*H + V.*V); % or sqrt(H.^2+V.^2)
figure
imshow(E, [])
```

[image]

Comment: Have my vote too, for being 8,342,602 times better at Octave than me, although multiplying that by my big, fat zero doesn't come to much ;-)